# Why can current flow in both directions through an LED?

Tags: electric-current, voltage

I know a diode only allows for current to flow in one direction. However, in my physics lab, the LED (a diode) turns on with both positive and negative current. Why is this the case? How is this possible? What could be happening for this LED to allow current to flow both directions?

Thank you

Comment: An ideal diode only allows current in one direction, but most diodes are not ideal

Comment: All diodes have 'leakage current'.   Meaning they all will conduct in the reverse direction.   However, LED's also have a photoelectric effect...  If there is light hitting the diode, it can conduct alot more current in the reverse direction.   Try wrapping the LED in black tape to block all light and run your experiment again.  Note "black" tape, not something that's just opaque.  Ideally you use metal even.   Using reverse biased LED's as photodetectors is actually a thing people do on purpose.   Not super efficient compared to a true photodetector, but cheap and it does work.

Comment: THere's also a voltage element... you didn't say what the reverse voltage you applied is.   All diodes will breakdown and conduct at a high enough reverse voltage.   The LED datasheet should (maybe) tell you what voltage that is.

Comment: The LED may thermally glow in reverse bias if your voltage is above the break through voltage. But that typically destroys the LED in a short time. The intended light emission mechanism should not work that way.

Comment: Perhaps they have "student proof" LEDs in the lab (with diodes selecting the direction of current flow, so they work no matter which way the voltage is applied).

Comment: I used to have an "LED" in my junk box that actually was two LEDs in the same package, wired in anti-parallel with each other. When current was driven through it in one direction, one of the two LED chips would light up, and when current was driven in the opposite direction, the other would light up. (This was really obvious because one of the chips glowed red, and the other one glowed in that weird, cold, yellowish color that we used to call "green" back in the day before _real_ green LEDs were invented.)

Comment: The post [LED in a circuit with alternating polarities](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/307868/edit) has an answer.

Comment: @Farcher Your link seems to be broken. (I just get an error message).

Comment: @SebastianRiese  "Student proof LEDs".  That's brilliant  LOL  I'd never thought of that.  It's definitely possible.  Of course, LED's cost a few pennies and blowing up components is part of the learning process (but I'm not a professor.. maybe they get irritated replacing stuff all the time!!!)   That would basically be a "AC LED"..  I've not seen such but I can imagine such would possibly exist.   It would be a POOR learning thing IMO as students could make gross circuit errors and not realize it.

Comment: It is an [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) with the title, [LED in a circuit with alternating polarities](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307868/led-in-a-circuit-with-alternating-polarities)